# how to switch between two map types in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have two `fragments` one is on full screen and the other is on the `upper right corner`. both `fragments` have different `map types`.
I want to `switch` the `full screen map type` with the `upper right corner map` on the click on the upper `right corner fragment`.how should I achieved this?

[image]

Comment: For that you need to set layout params to `MATCH_PARENT`.

Comment: for main fragment layout params set to `MATCH_PARENT` but how after click on the the right corner fragment should i Change just type of the main fragment or change size of both fragments?

Comment: Need to change both